# how to assign DbEntities object to my model object in EF Database first

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, ado.net-entity-data-model

I am doing a project for my course work, I am using  database first entity framework and got my DBContext class as

```
public partial class StudentDBEntities : DbContext
    {
         public DbSet<LoginDetail> LoginDetails { get; set; }
        public DbSet<StudentDetail> StudentDetails { get; set; }
        public DbSet<UserFriend> UserFriends { get; set; }
}
```

Now I created a model object as below to use this model to pass on view.

```
public class ViewStudentDetail
    {    
        public StudentDetail Student { get; set; }
        public UserFriend Friends { get; set; }

    }
```

here is my StudentDetail class created default

```
public partial class StudentDetail
    {
        public StudentDetail()
        {
            this.UserFriends = new HashSet<UserFriend>();
        }
        public string StudentName { get; set; }
        public string UnivName { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string EmailId { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<UserFriend> UserFriends { get; set; }
    }
```

In my View I have find a friend scenario and text box value passed is ViewStudentDetail.Friends.username.to the post method

My problem is that I want to assign the StudentDetails with the given username from DbContext object (that are already saved in database during registration) to the model object
In My controller i have like this

```
  StudentDBEntities DbAccess = new StudentDBEntities();
 ViewStudentDetail Studentdetails = new ViewStudentDetail();
    Studentdetails.Student = DbAccess.StudentDetails .Find(username);
```

This assignment is not working and is assigning null. 
Could you please tell me how to fetch the values in db to model object. Also if i need to assign each attribute to model please help me with the syntax to fetch from db object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [DbSet.Find()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696418%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) method searches only for PRIMARY KEY matches, it will not search all/any properties on an entity.

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
ViewStudentDetail.Student = DbAccess.StudentDetails.FirstOrDefault(student => student.Username == username);
```

If not, please provide more of your source code in your question.  Specifically, please include the generated entity classes.

Comment: hi kingdango,I have edited and added . please check if that is ok to get me an answer.

Comment: Please include the StudentDetail class.  If you are using Database First then this would have been generated for you.  Have you tried my suggestion to use .FirstOrDefault instead of .Find ?

Comment: Yes I used FirstOrDefault it throwed me this error.               Cannot implicitly convert type 'StudentNetwork.Models.StudentDetail' to 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet<StudentNetwork.Models.StudentDetail>'

Comment: I think you want to assign ViewStudentDetail.Student to a record from the database that matches based on username, right?  If so see my updated answer.

Comment: Hi kingdango, the above answer is just assigning null but the username provided has details in database, I have edited for more clartiy.

Comment: FirstOrDefault will return a record or NULL if one is not found.  Perhaps you do not have an exact match?  Try testing to see if you can ever retrieve anything, ViewStudentDetail.Student = DbAccess.StudentDetails.First();